# Opção collapsible do Materialize não funciona corretamente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, materialize

Estou utilizando o Framework Materialize para exibir uma lista.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa lista pode ser expandida, porém só funciona depois de recarregar o navegador várias vezes com CTRL + F5.

Quando eu carrego diretamente no HTML, funciona, mas quando carrego pelo JavaScript a lista, só recarregando várias vezes.

Eu utilizo Jquery, Materialize e API do Google Maps, já retirei o script do Google Maps mas não resolveu.

### Tentativas

- Já tentei carregar o script randomicamente: script.js?random=uniquid();
- Utilizar no-cache no html

Eu inspecionei o elemento html da lista e ele carrega todas as tags, inclusive o log não reporta nenhum erro.

Estou usando $(document).ready(function(){})

Answer (score 0):

Em testes que realizei, percebi que os elementos adicionados estaticamente funcionavam corretamente, então tentei adicionar o comando `$('.collapsible').collapsible();` após a inserção dos elementos, pelo JavaScript
e funcionou corretamente.